# Why did my reputation be decreased by 8 points and 4 points and increased on other site on 14

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I cannot see any downvotes but my reputation was decreased by 8 points on UI site: from 752 to 744. The same situation on http://dba.stackexchange.com site: from 852 to 848 (4 points). At the same time my stackoverflow.com account got additional 14 points. What is going on?

Comment: Please don't post the same question in three different places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reputation score is denormalized, so it is expected for it to vary slightly from the "real" value over time.** We periodically recalculate everyone's reputation to bring it in sync, roughly once per year.

Some ways reputation can be affected without being updated live:

- a user is deleted; this deletes all their votes
- a post is deleted
- a post is migrated to another site

You can always check

`/reputation`

to see the live calculation of your reputation, and optionally recalculate it to reflect the current, most correct, value.

Answer (score 5):

We are doing a [global recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-drop-in-reputation-find-out-reason-recalc/80865#80865) in order to bring in some new features.

Comment: have you plans to return these points? :)

Comment: Sure, get an upvote and you can have the points back. (;